Wavefunctions in the Landau levels as coherent states?
I'm interested to understand the algebraic method to analyse the Landau level problem.
To set up the problem (I will be using natural units), I consider the Hamiltonian:
$$ \hat{H}=(\hat{\mathbf{p}}-\hat{\mathbf{A}})^2 $$ In the algebraic method, I can find two sets of bosonic operators which commute with the Hamiltonian. One set is obtained by $\hat{b}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{\pi}_x-i\hat{\pi}_y)$ and $\hat{b}^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{\pi}_x+i\hat{\pi}_y)$ where $\hat{\pi}=\hat{\mathbf{p}}-\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ is the mechanical momentum. The Hamiltonian in terms of these operators is $$\hat{H}=2(\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b}+\frac{1}{2})$$ which is just the harmonic oscillator.
The other set of bosonic operators are given by $\hat{d}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{X}+i\hat{Y})$ and $\hat{d}^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{X}-i\hat{Y})$ where $\hat{X}=\hat{x}-\hat{\pi}_y$ and  $\hat{Y}=\hat{y}+\hat{\pi}_x$ are the guiding centers.
Both of these two sets of bosonic algebras obey Heisenberg algebras, and I believe the eigenfunctions can be written as: $|n,m>$ where $n$ and $m$ are eigenvalues of the $\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b}$ and $\hat{d}^\dagger\hat{d}$ operators respectively, and so $n,m=0, 1,...$. Explicitly, this is given by:$$|n,m> \propto (\hat{b}^\dagger)^n(\hat{d}^\dagger)^m|0,0>.$$
I have also heard that coherent states can be used to represent the same eigenstates (see Stack Exchange answer here). Which of the bosonic operators should I use to create coherent states? Why are coherent states used to represent the Landau level eigenstates?
